# Using classes in routing express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I decided to rewrite the code from functions to classes. However, I encountered such a problem that my this undefined

Routing

```
// router.js

const ExampleController = require('./ExampleController');
const instanceOfExampleController = new ExampleController();

// Require express and other dependencies

app.post('/post-to-login', instanceOfExampleController.login) // An error appears inside the method
```

And controller

```
// My Controller

class ExampleController {

// Private method
myPrivateMethod(info) {
    return info.toUpperCase();
}

login(req, res, next) {
    console.log('----------------------');
    console.log(this); // Here "this" equal of undefined!
    console.log('----------------------');
    const someValue = this.myPrivateMethod(req.body.info); // Not work!
    res.send(someValue);
 };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceOfExampleController.login.bind(instanceOfExampleController)` will do the trick. The function loses its context once it's being called directly.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
app.post('/post-to-login', function (req, res, next) {
  instanceOfExampleController.login(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: To my surprise, none of the ways you suggested helped me. The call context for "this" is undefined